# How do I fix Module not found error in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, plotly

In python when using plotly and sklearn I installed both packages and checked that their locations were added to my system environment variables but I still get the error "No module named 'plotly'" and same for sklearn and I don't know what else to do. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please give a detailed explanation of your question and the expected output so that others can understand it and answer it. I suggest you to read asking [guidelines of Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please show your code and the exact error message.  Are you encountering the error from `jupyter`?  ... `ipython`? ... commandline? ... an IDE?  It will help potential responders to know more.

Comment: Did you search the [previous questions/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%22module+not+found%22) for something similar?

Comment: I had searched previous questions but nothing worked with my issue. Yes I am using an IDE, emacs. So I was able to fix it but I still don't know why what I did worked. Normally when installing packages I just use the command "python install" and then whatever I need and this has worked for every other package I installed but not these. Then I read somewhere that another command is "python -m pip install -U" and then the package and that ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are operating within the virtual environment?
Try `pip list` to show what is installed in this environment. If `plotly` and `sklearn` are not listed, you are either not operating within the virtual environment when executing the script or you haven't installed the modules within the virtualenv

Comment: are you executing it from an IDE? if its in the virtual env you will need to provide details where you run it from to find the issue

Comment: I had searched previous questions but nothing worked with my issued. Yes I am using an IDE, emacs. So I was able to fix it but I still don't know why what I did worked. Normally when installing packages I just use the command "python install" and then whatever I need which worked for every other package I have installed but then I read somewhere that another command is "python -m pip install -U" and then the package and that ended up working.